# removeChild() not working?

Tags: javascript, removechild

Clearly I'm doing something wrong here, but not being a native javascript guy, I'm having trouble spotting it.

I accidentally added a whole lot of child nodes to the head of some html that I'm using to populate webViews in my iOS app (I usually program in objc). This happened because I used document.head.appendChild each time I loaded the page, without checking if a node already existed like the one I wanted. So now I have multiples of the desired nodes. doh!

So now I am trying to write a function to remove them all again.

This is what I have:

```
function removeThemAgain() {
    if (document.head.hasChildNodes()) {
        console.log('has child nodes');
        for (var i = document.head.childNodes.length - 1; i >=  0; i--) {
            if (document.head.childNodes[i].innerHTML ==  'body * {-webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;}'){
                console.log('removing i == ' + i + ' ' + document.head.childNodes[i].innerHTML);
                document.head.removeChild(document.head.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, it is finding the nodes, as the console.log is reporting that it is removing the nodes (as I would expect per my code), but when I check to see if they are still there, they haven't really gone at all!

eg:

> [Log] removing i == 7 body * {-webkit-text-size-adjust:none
>   !important;}
>
> [Log] removing i == 6 body * {-webkit-text-size-adjust:none
>   !important;}

they were created with

```
var myStyle = document.createElement('style');  
myStyle.innerHTML = 'body * {-webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;}'; 
document.head.appendChild(myStyle);
```

I'm sure it's something obvious, but right now the reason is eluding me.

any ideas as to why these are not actually being removed?

Comment: Is there any possibility of that style being present 3 times or more? They are in different nodes. What makes you think they come from same thing?

Comment: off topic, but why not fix it at the source?

Comment: thanks for the replies. I will fix it at the source as well, but I need to remove the damage that it has already done to multiple html files that have also been updated in other ways, so I cannot just undo this part.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Yes! In my test file the line of code is present 4 times. Does that make a difference? I'm not sure what you mean by "What makes you think they came from the same thing"? (also, I am stepping away from my desk for a while but will back soon)

Comment: @narco Your code works properly at runtime in a web browser. I don't understand what you mean by "I need to remove the damage that it has already done to multiple html files that have also been updated in other ways". How are the **files** affected by this?

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting multiple copies of the node. Each time you load the page, it starts with the original HTML file, not the modifications from the previous load. If you add the node when you load the page, you'll just get one copy of it.

Comment: As I said, this is for within an iOS app. Sometimes in an iOS app you use html to display data for the various benefits of html. My app has thousands of html files, and these files are sometimes edited and saved by the app itself. Unfortunately I was creating these nodes when opening each html file, and then when it was edited and saved, it saved the node with the file, only to add another next time it was opened. Since there are thousands of such files I want a way to edit them without doing manually.

Comment: @KosmasPapadatos  thanks for checking that the code works in a web browser. It must be something stupid I am doing elsewhere. Although I have just realised I could do it in objective-C, treat the html as a text file and just edit that. That would be easy and I am much more comfortable there. However, I  I would still like to know why this isn't working for me.

Comment: @narco Correct me if I'm wrong but - are you expecting this code to change the contents of the html file?

Comment: @KosmasPapadatos aha! I thought I was saving the file afterwards (via objc), but now that I look at it, it appears I wasn't. Thanks (yes, it was a stupid mistake!) (and btw no, I wasn't expecting that code by itself to save)

Comment: @narco Haha, I'm glad you found out what the problem was ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct and does the job it's supposed to. I suppose you meant to save a snapshot of the runtime html back into the file but you didn't do **that** properly.